Sticky Mod Podge
Help!  I'm decorating small tins with journaling items and then covering it all with MP. It's been well over 4 weeks and the tin still feels tacky. Is there another product to use instead. My tins will be Christmas gifts. Many thanks!

Hi, welcome to Arts & Crafts! You write "I'm decorating with" "and then covering it with MP": have you used another type of glue for that first step?

Nope. Just the Mod Podge. Xo

Less modge podge. If it's still sticky then you're likely using too much, simply reduce the amount that you're using. Brush it on with a poster paint brush and spread it out thinly.

Many, many thanks.
